# set calculated field as not nullable

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have a calculated field in MSSQL table view.

```
CAST((MyCalcField) AS BIT) AS UsersManager
```

When Entity Framework create model of this view it always set UsersManager field as nullable. Is it possible to using SQL to set field as not nullable? I know what I set set field type directly in EF model but I would like to keep field type structure in MSSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `ISNULL`

```
ISNULL(CAST((MyCalcField) AS BIT), 0) AS UsersManager
```